# Android - Activity transition crash with ActionBarActivity

Tags: android, transition, material-design

I'm currently trying to implement Material Design activity transitions. For a reason i really don't know, it crashes. Can someone give me a clue? (I don't know if it's important, but inside my MainActivity, i've a ViewPager with Fragments from which I try to start the next Activity)

Thanks a lot for your help.

My code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {
    (...)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i("TAAG", "MainActivity::onCreate1");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.i("TAAG", "MainActivity::onCreate2");
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS);
        Log.i("TAAG", "MainActivity::onCreate3");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.i("TAAG", "MainActivity::onCreate4");
        (...)
    }
```

Here are the logs:

```
11-13 18:12:36.442    1098-1098/I/TAAG﹕ MainActivity::onCreate1
11-13 18:12:36.544    1098-1098/I/TAAG﹕ MainActivity::onCreate2
11-13 18:12:36.559    1098-1098/E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: mypackage, PID: 1098
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{mypackage/mypackage.MainActivity}: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.requestFeature(PhoneWindow.java:301)
            at mypackage.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:42)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: Problem starts here at mypackage.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:42). what is at line 42 inside onCreate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try calling `getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS);` before `super.onCreate()`.